# TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, mern

I'm following a pdf course - `full-stack-react-projects` by *Shama Hoque*. In other to solve the problem I updated npm and node globally using the command line, but I still get this error message - **`throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');`** You can find the code here - https://github.com/Shittu1/mern-skeleton. My server.js file is as follows:

```
import config from './../config/config';
import app from './express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUri);

mongoose.connection.on('error', { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
   throw new error(`Unable to connect to the database ${mongoUri}`);
})

app.listen(config.port, (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.info('Server started on port: ', config.port)
})
```

Please, I need someone to help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where the error handler takes parameters other than the handler function, have you tried to set it up per the documentation?

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
   throw new error(`Unable to connect to the database ${config.mongoUri}`);
})
```

Side note, in your code, mongoUri is not defined, did you mean config.mongoUri?

**Documentation**
From https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

> To handle errors after initial connection was established, you should
>   listen for error events on the connection. However, you still need to
>   handle initial connection errors as shown above.

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => { logError(err); });
```